# Getting bootstrap dropdown value return to work in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a value (player) from the dropdown select. Once I click the dropdown button, I want the value 'player' to get sent to flask and render the new player's image on the website.
HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04" name="player" value="{{ player }}">
          {% for key, value in team.items() %}
            <option value={{ value }}>{{ value }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Select</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
    <img src="/static/{{ player }}.png" alt="{{ player }}">
```

Flask:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    player = okc[1628983]
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("this posted")
        player = request.form.get('player')
        print(request.form.get('player'))
        return render_template("index.html", team=okc, player=player)
    return render_template("index.html", team=okc, player=player)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button wasn't posting - changed type from button to submit

Answer (score 0):

instead of your:

`player = request.form.get('player')`

you can try this:

`player = request.form['player']`

Comment: thanks for taking the time to comment, but that didn't work either. I think there is something with how I named the button or within the html that isn't right. I might be completely wrong, I am fairly new to this.

Comment: if your problem doesn't solved, just explain it more up, and I will help you as I can

Comment: I want the user to select a name from the dropdown, and when they click the button the image updates to a picture that is associated with that player. Currently, when they click the button, the image doesn't change. The image is named after the player: player_name.png.

Comment: I am not sure if when I click the button, it actually POSTs. I think that might be the first issue I have.

Comment: I fixed the POST issue by changing the button type to "submit" instead of "button".  Now, it kind of works! Except the only issue is that it only gets the player's first name when it updates instead of the full name. I will try to update the original post with the current code.

Comment: Finally figured it out... when I was initializing the dropdown list, I didn't have {{ value }} in parentheses so it was only recognizing the first word. Thanks for all the help! I learned a lot